# webRTC nodejs not working after deployment in vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I have developed and deployed nodejs webrtc still not working

after deployment

1. Design not working
2. Live video communication is also not working

this is the live link [click here](https://live-webrtc.vercel.app)

this is git repo link [click here](https://github.com/MujmillahammedDafedar/webrtc_nodejs2)

Answer (score 1):

The demo signaling server for that (long since deprecated) package is no longer running at that address anymore. Run your own.

Answer (score 0):

Your socket isn't connecting. You need to setup your cors with the name of the frontend website.

[image]